# How to loop through a certain column to create multiple plots python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, plot, seaborn

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'Y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'Season': [1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2]})
test


    X   Y   Season
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   4   4   2
4   5   5   1
5   6   6   3
6   7   7   2
7   8   8   1
8   9   9   3
9   10  10  2
```

How could I go about looping through the season column and plotting all the points for said seasons (on different plots)? I've searched questions similar to this and attempted the code, but none seem to be quite the same as this particular situation. Thanks!

EDIT: I would like the plots to be sns regplots if possible

Comment: You can group by and made a plot for each season. Eventually you could made it interactive wit lh a drop-down menu in plotly.

Comment: `test.groupby('Season').plot(x='X', y='Y')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want seaborn regplots, try [`lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot(data=test, x='X', y='Y',row='Season')
```